# Error while pressing the button " type object "my model" has no attribute "my action" - Odoo 10

Tags: button, attributes, odoo, models, odoo-10

I'm working on Odoo 10. When I click on the button, get mentioned error.

I want to convert a contact in partner so I need create a new line in another table with the values I put in the *.create(vals).*

The following links are some extracts of my code , hope you can help me.

my class : [model.py](http://prntscr.com/e6fcde)

my view : [model_view.xml](http://prntscr.com/e6fdbd)

my error : [server trace back](http://prntscr.com/e6femr)

Comment: Please add your error image into your question.

Comment: Thank you for correcting my message but have you any idea to fix my error ?

Comment: Can't you just copy paste your code like everyone ? We use screen printing for the things that we cannot write down.

Comment: It's not in my habits to post on the forums, sorry for not doing the perfect thing my lord

Comment: Lord Majikat's request was just right. Please edit your question, so we get all things at once.

Comment: But I don't know how to create these grey spaces, I'm new in stackoverflow and any other forum

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your code at all. You inherit a model called `test.res.partner` and I don't know if you already created it. That may be the issue.

It could be also the fact that you may no be importing your model.py file if this module inherits another one that you have already created.

In general this message indicates that the method `convert_prospect` does not exist in the model `test.res.partner`.

But seeing how you write your view (like using xpath in a view that does not inherit from another one) you should rework your fundamentals.

Ah and don't call that `prospect()` at the end.

Comment: I had the model in another python file but then i gathered both files like that : http://prntscr.com/e6ienv

Comment: What happens if you don't call `partner()` in the end ? Have you restarted your server before making more tests ?

Comment: I always restart my server when I modify my python's code and it makes an Internal server error if I dont call partner()

Comment: Ah. On Odoo10, there is no openerp anymore. So this line `from openerp import fields, models, api` must be `from odoo import fields, models, api`. But that is strange. I've coded with Odoo since v8 and never had to call my models after defining them.

Comment: Are those two files the only one that you use ? Because this should definitely work. I think that you would have to re-install Odoo for all the bugs that you're experiencing.

Comment: About this module , that are the only 2 files that I use yes , I will try to clear my VM but I don't think that it will resolve my problem.

Comment: Last try for me : check on your indentations. Make it consistent (always use tabs or always use spaces). PEP8 suggests we use spaces. Select all element in your files (I see you're using Sublime Text) `Ctrl + A`. Select `View>Indentation>Convert Indentation to Spaces`.

Comment: I found that what was the issue , my button wasn't in the <form> so ofc it couldn't work properly ...

Comment: Well I told you about you using xpath in my answer. But, lucky you. Happy you solved your problem.